# 2D cross-correlation of a 6x6 array with three 3x3 kernels

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, convolution

I have a 6x6 matrix: e.g. matrix `A`

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

I also have a 3x3x3 matrix: e.g. matrix `B`

```
array([[[ 1, 7, 2],
        [ 5, 9, 3],
        [ 2, 8, 6]],

       [[ 3, 4, 6],
        [ 6, 8, 9],
        [ 4, 2, 8]],

       [[ 6, 4, 7],
        [ 8, 7, 8],
        [ 4, 4, 7]]])
```

Finally, I have a 3x4x4 matrix `C`, (4 rows, 4 columns, 3 dimensions), that's empty (filled with `0`s)

I want to multiply each "3rd dimension" of `B` (i.e. `[1,:,:]`,`[2,:,:]`,`[3,:,:]`) with `A`. However, for each dimension I want to multiply `B` in "windows", sliding by 1 each time across `A` till I cannot go further, at which point I move back to the beginning, slide 1 unit down and again sliding across one-by-one multiplying `B` with `A`, till the end, then move down and repeat till you don't go over the border. The results being stored in the respective "3rd dimension" of matrix `C`. So my result would be a `[3x4x4]` matrix.

Ex. (multiplication is dot product giving a scalar value, `np.sum((np.multiply(x,y)))`), so...

imagining `B` "overtop" of `A`, starting in the right corner, I multiply that 3x3 part of `A` with `B`s [1x3x3] part storing the result in `C`...

referring to 1st unit (located in 1st row and 1st column) in the 1st dimension of `C`...

`C[1,0,0]` = 340. because `[[0,1,2],[6,7,8],[12,13,4]]` dot product `[[1,7,2],[5,9,3],[2,8,6]]`

sliding `B` matrix over by 1 on `A`, and storing my 2nd result in `C`...

`C[1,0,1]` = 383. because `[[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[13,14,15]]` dot product `[[1,7,2],[5,9,3],[2,8,6]]`

Then repeat this procedure of sliding across and down and across and ..., for `B[2,:,:]` and `B[3,:,:]` over `A` again, storing in `C2,:,:]` and `C[3,:,:]` respectively.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you're asking about [tag:tensors], and I can't understand your custom definition of combining matrix- and dot- multiplication to get a 4x4x3 result.

Comment: What you want to do sounds more like [2D convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_discrete_convolution) to me, rather than matrix multiplication... Is that what you want?

Comment: Are you experiencing a *mathematical*  problem or a *programming* (*implementation*) one?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build the convolutional part of a VERY simple CNN using Numpy and no CovNet toolkits @Praveen.

Comment: If I use numpy.dot() on two 3x3 matrix I will get a 3x3 resulting matrix, but I'm trying to get the dot product as a scalar value @smci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking about 2D cross-correlation with three different kernels, rather than straightforward matrix multiplication.

The following piece of code is not the most efficient way to do this, but does this give you the answer you are looking for? I'm using [`scipy.signal.correlate2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html) to achieve 2D correlation here...

```
>>> from scipy.signal import correlate2d
>>> C = np.dstack([correlate2d(A, B[:, :, i], 'valid') for i in range(B.shape[2])])
>>> C.shape
(4, 4, 3)
>>> C
array([[[ 333,  316,  464],
        [ 372,  369,  520],
        [ 411,  422,  576],
        [ 450,  475,  632]],

       [[ 567,  634,  800],
        [ 606,  687,  856],
        [ 645,  740,  912],
        [ 684,  793,  968]],

       [[ 801,  952, 1136],
        [ 840, 1005, 1192],
        [ 879, 1058, 1248],
        [ 918, 1111, 1304]],

       [[1035, 1270, 1472],
        [1074, 1323, 1528],
        [1113, 1376, 1584],
        [1152, 1429, 1640]]])
```

Here's a more "fun" way of doing this which doesn't use scipy, but using [`stride_tricks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) instead. I'm not sure if it's more efficient:

```
>>> import numpy.lib.stride_tricks as st
>>> s, t = A.strides
>>> i, j = A.shape
>>> k, l, m = B.shape
>>> D = st.as_strided(A, shape=(i-k+1, j-l+1, k, l), strides=(s, t, s, t))
>>> E = np.einsum('ijkl,klm->ijm', D, B)
>>> (E == C).all()
True
```

Comment: You want to use `correlate` instead of `convolve`.  `correlate` does not rotate the kernel first prior to the dot product.  If you look at the example calculations, the kernel is not rotated.

Comment: @rayryeng That's a good point. We don't want flipping of axes.

Comment: Exactly.  `scipy.signal.correlate` should do the same job without rotating each kernel.... or you can rotate the kernel yourself and let `convolve` undo the rotation.  Either way... but this is the correct answer. Have a vote from me.  I was about to write the answer and you beat me to it.

Comment: @Praveen, if it's not too late, I'm actually confused by your output. By [4x4x3] I meant a matrix with 4 rows, 4 columns, and 3 dimensions. I realize I should of wrote [3x4x4]. This is because a 3x3 window can only fit into a 6x6 matrix 4 times without going over the border. I don't actually understand how there can be 4 outputs with 3 kernels. Thanks

Comment: @Bn.F76 A `(4, 4, 3)` array is exactly what you wanted, with the three kernels along the last axis. If you want a `(3, 4, 4)` array, just try `C.transpose(2, 0, 1)`, which will move the last axis in front, so that when you print it out, you'll see three 4x4 matrices.